# How to access variables that are defined in a separate QML file?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt-quick

I'm unable to access variables in a separate file.

Down below is part of my code:

```qml
// Style.qml

import QtQuick

QtObject {
    property int mainWindowWidth: 1024
    property int mainWindowHeight: 768
}
```

```qml
// Main.qml

import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Window

Window {
    id: root
    width: Style.mainWindowWidth
    height: Style.mainWindowHeight
    minimumWidth: width
    minimumHeight: height
    maximumWidth: width
    maximumHeight: height
    visible: true
    title: "Sampletext"
}
```

It compiles fine but when I run it, I get an error saying:

> Unable to assign [undefined] to int where the line width: Style.mainWindowWidth is located.

How do I fix this?

Comment: You have to declare the Style object as a singleton to use it in this way. Read [this](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/mobile/9781788995399/5/ch05lvl1sec45/theming-the-application-with-a-qml-singleton) article, looks it close to your needs. Besides that, I would advice to read some QML book, like [this one](https://www.qt.io/product/qt6/qml-book) for more info.

Comment: I agree with folibis. Singleton would be a nice way to do this, else you will have to instantiate the component `Style { id: style }` before you can access the properties. There is already a singleton in `cmake` answer. Are you using `cmake` or `qmake`?

Answer (score 0):

You should create an instance of the `Style` component or define `Style` as a singleton component.
Definition of `Style` as singleton is as follows:

###### Style.qml

```
pragma Singleton

import QtQuick

QtObject {
    property int mainWindowWidth: 1024
    property int mainWindowHeight: 768
}
```

###### CMakeLists.txt:

```
set_source_files_properties(
    Style.qml
    PROPERTIES QT_QML_SINGLETON_TYPE True
)

qt6_add_qml_module(appExample
    URI appExample
    VERSION 1.0
    QML_FILES
        Main.qml
        Style.qml
)
```

###### Main.qml

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Window

import appExample

Window {
    id: root
    width: Style.mainWindowWidth
    height: Style.mainWindowHeight
    minimumWidth: width
    minimumHeight: height
    maximumWidth: width
    maximumHeight: height
    visible: true
    title: "Sample Text"
}
```